# How to add a subject to an email being sent with gmail?

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, gmail, subject

I am trying to send an email using GMAIL with a subject and a message. I have succeeded in sending an email using GMAIL without the implementation of `subject` and have also been able to receieve the email. However whenever I try to add a subject the program simply does not work.

```
import smtplib
fromx = 'email@gmail.com'
to  = 'email1@gmail.com'
subject = 'subject' #Line that causes trouble
msg = 'example'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')
server.sendmail(fromx, to, subject , msg) #'subject'Causes trouble
server.quit()
```

error line:

```
server.sendmail(fromx, to, subject , msg) #'subject'Causes trouble
```

Comment: RTFM? https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail: `(from_addr, to_addr, msg, mail_options)`.

Comment: Read automate the boring stuff with python https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The call to `smtplib.SMTP.sendmail()` does not take a `subject` parameter. See [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) for instructions on how to call it.

Subject lines, along with all other headers, are included as part of the message in a format called RFC822 format, after the now-obsolete document that originally defined the format.  Make your message conform to that format, like so:

```
import smtplib
fromx = 'xxx@gmail.com'
to  = 'xxx@gmail.com'
subject = 'subject' #Line that causes trouble
msg = 'Subject:{}\n\nexample'.format(subject)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxx')
server.sendmail(fromx, to, msg)
server.quit()
```

Of course, the easier way to conform your message to all appropriate standards is to use the Python [`email.message`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html) standard library, like so:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

fromx = 'xxx@gmail.com'
to  = 'xxx@gmail.com'
msg = MIMEText('example')
msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
msg['From'] = fromx
msg['To'] = to

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxx')
server.sendmail(fromx, to, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

[Other examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#email-examples) are also available.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use a package like [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail). Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer.

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP("email.gmail.com", "password")
yag.send("email1.gmail.com", "subject", "contents")
```

Install with `pip install yagmail`

Comment: I did actually try this before hand. Didn't seem to work.